# Load part of a map from openstreet to folium/leaflet

Tags: python, geolocation, maps, interactive

I´m using folium to plot an interactive map, so far it is working fine, but I'm interested in just a part of the map and not all  the streets polygons.

It is possible to take just a part of the map E.G only Europe and only polygons at country level? to have a Light weight map.

Answer (score 0):

You can define max-zoom level for leaflet, surely `folium` would also allow you to do this. If for some reason you want to disable zoom/panning, again you should be able to.

```js
new L.Map('map', { zoomControl:false });
```

and maybe a similar API for panning.

HTH.